# CSHTML code not parsing in IE7

Tags: webmatrix, razor

I am working on revising our office intranet site from .ASP under IIS5 to CSHTML under IIS7, and I am using WebMatrix to work on the code. I am running into a problem where any CSHTML "@" codes are not being parsed by the browser, and instead is the text is just being dumped straight to the display. For example:

```
@{ 
    var db = Database.Open("DB_Name"); 
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY Row_ID";
 }
```

is appearing on the page as

@{ 
    var db = Database.Open("DB_Name"); 
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY Row_ID"; 
 }

I am trying to view these pages with IE7 running on XP SP3. What little information I have found points to a possible issue with Microsoft.Data.dll, but I am not sure what it could be. I do know that the dll is not on the machine I am using to view the pages.

Comment: Browser should receive plain HTML, all those character should be processed by server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technology called "CSHTML under IIS7". CSHTML is file extension used for Razor view engine for ASP.NET / MVC. [More details here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx). It should not be send to browser in this way, browser should receive pure HTML. Make sure that in IIS settings the page extension is handled by ASP.NET.

Comment: I found the problem - it was a matter of not having the correct version of ASP.NET running on the server, so I had to reinstall it, and start recoding pages using CSHTML.